# Find String in text file using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I would like to loop on every line of my .txt file within my batch script, and get every string in it.

My file is like

```
'string number 1' 'string number 2' 'string number 3'
'string number 11' 'string just string'
//...
```

And I would like to know how to get every strings surrounded by simple quotes.

I hope I'm clear enough.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q35266036.txt"
(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "line=%%a"
 SET "line=!line:'="!"
 FOR %%w IN (!line!) DO echo '%%~w'
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q35266036.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

Simply, read each file to `%%a` then put in `line` for strng-manipulation.

replace each <kbd>'</kbd> with <kbd>"</kbd>

process as a space-separated list of double-quotes strings.

remove the quotes and replace with single-quotes (if required)

---

Revision to save first 2 items

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q35266036.txt"
set "item1="
set "item2="
(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "line=%%a"
 SET "line=!line:'="!"
 FOR %%w IN (!line!) DO (
  echo '%%~w'
  if defined item1 if not defined item2 set "item2=%%~w"
  if not defined item1 set "item1=%%~w"
 )
)
)>"%outfile%"

echo item1=%item1%
echo item2=%item2%

GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: This is just perfect !! Thank you very much for your time and for the explanations !!

Comment: Just one more question, if I want for example to store the first word, and the second, and use them after the "second" for ? I tried doing this but it seems like it's not working ..
    SET "i=0"
 FOR %%w IN (!line!) DO (
  echo '%%~w'
  IF !i! EQU "0" (
    SET i=1
    SET "p1='%%~w'"
    echo !p1!
  )
  IF !i! EQU "1" (
    SET i=1
    SET "p2='%%~w'"
    echo !p2!
  )
 )
 echo. '!p1!'
 echo. '!p2!'

Comment: Basically I would like to send all these parameters to a sql script, so I need them all at once